# configure nginx to work with django and moodle

Tags: php, nginx, moodle

I'm trying to configure nginx to run a moodle website in parallel to a django one and a jellyfin one. My domain name is `www.example.com` and I would like to set everything that ends with `www.example.com/moodle` to the moodle site and all non-moodle pages to be handled by django and jellyfin.

The following `nginx` configuration worked for django and jellyfin:

```
upstream champhy {
    server unix:/mnt/data1/django_apps/champhy/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    server_name www.example.com; # managed by Certbot

    location /jellyfin {
            return 302 $scheme://$host/jellyfin/;
    }
    location /jellyfin/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8096/jellyfin/;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
            proxy_buffering off;
    }

    location /media  {
            alias /mnt/data1/data; 
            client_max_body_size 50m;
    }
    location /static {
            client_max_body_size 50m;
            alias /mnt/data1/django_static/champhy;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I read a lot of documentation about moodle but I can't figure out how to make it work. I'm very new to php and according to [this](https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Nginx), [this](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-moodle-3-3-2-ubuntu-17-04-17-10-nginx-mariadb-php-support/) and [that](https://techexpert.tips/moodle/moodle-installation-nginx/) I tried to add new locations like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;        
}

location /dataroot/ {
    internal;
    alias /var/www/html/moodledata/;
}

location ~ /moodle/(.\+.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^moodle/(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index            index.php;
    fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    include                  fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

But after a lot of effort I keep on failing. Note that when I disable django and jellyfin and I run only moodle on `www.example.com`, it works. Please, help me, I'm a teacher who want to get ready for his students before the coming lockdown... thx

Comment: Can you try:
Remove the block:
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;        
}

add: try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
bellow: location ~ /moodle/(.\+.php(/|$) {
-- SEE: https://pastebin.pl/view/d8399619

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the little help I got here, I could fix my problem... here is my current nginx configuration:

```
upstream champhy {
    server unix:/mnt/data1/django_apps/champhy/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.ch/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.ch/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    server_name www.example.com; # managed by Certbot

    # jellyfin
    location /jellyfin {
        return 302 $scheme://$host/jellyfin/;
    }
    location /jellyfin/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8096/jellyfin/;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }

    # server authenticated medias for tepepe
    location /protected_media/ {
        client_max_body_size 50m;
        add_header X-Accel-Buffering yes;
        add_header X-Accel-Limit-Rate off;
        alias      /mnt/data1/data/tepepe/protected_media/;
        expires 24h;
        internal;
    }

    #champhy media
    location /media  {
        alias /mnt/data1/data; 
        client_max_body_size 50m;
    }
    #champhy static
    location /static {
        client_max_body_size 50m;
        alias /mnt/data1/django_static/champhy; 
    }

    root /var/www/html/;
    location /dataroot/ {
        internal;
        alias /mnt/data1/moodle-data/;
    }

    location ~ /moodle/(.+\.php)?(/|$)? {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/?.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        include                  /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index           index.php;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://champhy;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```